# Is it possible to change multible items in list to same?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
list = ['_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ']   
index = [1,4]
letter = 'm'
```

So is there any away to change lists 1 and 4 to be 'm' using index and letter?

Thanks for help!

Comment: you should search existing SO answers before posting. The reason for so many downvotes is that this question has been answered multiple times!

Comment: Porbably shouldn't use `list` as the name, that would conflict with the built-in function [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-list).

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
for i in index:
    list[i] = letter
```

Comment: Thanks! That help a lot.

Comment: I would also add `if i < len(lst):`, otherwise `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` errors could happen.

Comment: Even `if abs(i) < len(lst)` to be super thorough, to also cover negative indices such as `-56`.

Answer (score 2):

> Many solutions trying same old approach here using `loop`:

Here is different approach:

> Without any loop:

```
list_1 = ['_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ','_']
index = [1,4]
letter = 'm'

list(map(lambda x:(list_1.__setitem__(x,letter)),index))
print(list_1)
```

> output:

```
['_ ', 'm', '_ ', '_ ', 'm']
```

Some cookies:

```
import operator

list(map(lambda x:operator.setitem(list_1, x, letter),index))
print(list_1)
```

> output:

```
['_ ', 'm', '_ ', '_ ', 'm']
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you are trying to achieve is known as fancy indexing - using a list of indexes. But, this is possible for Numpy arrays, not in the case f simple python lists. So, a possible solution cold be:

```
import numpy as np
mylist = ['_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ']
index = [1,4]
letter = 'm'

list_changed=np.array(mylist)
list_changed[index]=letter
print list_changed
```

Comment: "Fancy indexing" is a numpy term, not a python one.

Comment: The question "Is it possible to change multiple items in list to same?" doesnot restrict me to use fancy indexing term